# Enabling back/fwd key events for an Ajax Application

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, dom-events, hashchange

I have an application which works heavily on AJAX. However I want to have navigation functionalities in it. To spoof the url, I am changing the location.hash, to generate URL. But if I use back/fwd, only the url changes, but page wont reload. How can I override the `hstory.back` to reload the page.

Comment: You might want to rename the title of the question to be a bit more specific. How about "Reloading a page with ajax when user clicks the browser back button" or something similar?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any other way than continuous polling to implement this behaviour. An implementation might look like this:

```
var lastHash = '';

function pollHash() {
    if(lastHash !== location.hash) {
        lastHash = location.hash;
        // hash has changed, so do stuff:
        alert(lastHash);
    }
}

setInterval(pollHash, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful. A small improvement can be added to it, if you wrap the whole expression in a function statement which you invoke immediately, and the return value of that function would be the function you wrote. This way you can eliminate a global binding.

Comment: I think this is what Török was talking about. Seems to work fine.  Feels a little cleaner because of the encapsulation.

var hashChecker = function(){
 lastHash = location.hash;
 return setInterval(function() {
     if(lastHash !== location.hash) {
      lastHash = location.hash;
     }
 }, 50);
}()

Answer (score 3):

You can't exactly capture the back event, but most of these problems have been solved - and a good thing too, it's a *hard* problem.

Take a look at [really simple history](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) (aka RSH) and either implement it or work through it to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this question will be more or less the same as my answers for these questions:

- [How to show Ajax requests in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205900/how-to-show-ajax-requests-in-url/3276206#3276206)
- [How does Gmail handle back/forward in rich JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460041/how-does-gmail-handle-back-forward-in-rich-javascript/3460269#3460269)

In summary, two projects that you'll probably want to look at which explain the whole hashchange process and using it with ajax are:

- [jQuery History](http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-history) (using hashes to manage your pages state and bind to changes to update your page).
- [jQuery Ajaxy](http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy) (ajax extension for jQuery History, to allow for complete ajax websites while being completely unobtrusive and gracefully degradable).

Answer (score 0):

The balupton answers are really great.

But you also have another jQuery Plugin to handle your ajax requests, it is [address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/).