# independent Cross Browser Library to handle location.hash

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, hash

I need an independent Cross Browser Javascript Library to handle location.hash. not jQuery Specific. not dojo.hash. and if thats makes use of HTML 5 thats always welcome

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of [native hashchange](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#event-hashchange) support (IE8+, FFx 3.6+, WebKits from 528+), you'll need to [poll the location hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629765/enabling-back-fwd-key-events-for-an-ajax-application/629817#629817) for changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any lib, but you can use a cross-browser function to handle the location.hash and then integrate it into your desired lib.
You could use the [watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269633/javascript-watch-for-object-properties-changes) property implementation to act as an observer over the "document.location.hash" object. Then, the syntax would be something like :
`window.location.watch(
  'hash',
  function(id,oldVal,newVal){
     console.log("the window's hash value has changed from "+oldval+" to "+newVal);
  }
);`
if you want to do it this way, not to wait for an existing library to implement their own cross-browser method, I find the "watch" method as a very good start. You can see disscutions on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change).

Answer (score 0):

This has all you need:
[The All-In-One Entirely-Not-Alphabetical No-Bullshit Guide to HTML5 Fallbacks](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)
You can see different libraries under the **Browser State Management** section.

For a good hash change library see this one: [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)